# Xamarin.UITest: How to select a next element of the current node

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-ui-automation, xamarin.uitest

Is there any way to select a next element of the current node using `Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery`?

Here is a REPL source:

```
[CalabashRootView > ... > UIView]                                              
  [UILabel]
  [UIButton] label: "arrow prev"
    [UIImageView] id: "arrow-prev.png"
  [iLobby_iOS_Controls_UIAnimatedButtonView]
  [UILabel] label: "Tell us about yourself",  text: "Tell us about yourself"
  [UILabel] label: "FIRST AND LAST NAME",  text: "FIRST AND LAST NAME"
  [UILabel] label: "*",  text: "*"
  [UITextField]
    [UIImageView]
    [_UITextFieldContentView]
    [UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement]
  [UILabel] label: "COMPANY",  text: "COMPANY"
  [UITextField]
    [UIImageView]
    [_UITextFieldContentView]
    [UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement]
```

The challenge is select UITextField element next to UILabel

I looking for a similar way like xPath do. In my case it would look like:

```
//UILabel[@text='FIRST AND LAST NAME']/following::UITextField
```

Any Idea? Our app is written in Xamarin.iOS (no Xamarin.Forms).

Comment: Hi Sergey! Which framework/language are you using for your app: Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.iOS, React Native, Swift or ObjC?

Comment: Hi Brandon! We are using Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Great! I'll work on the answer now. I also updated the question & tags to include Xamarin.iOS which hopefully helps future Xamarin.iOS devs with the same question in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

The best way to identify UI controls with Xamarin.UITest is to assign a unique identifier to each control in the source code of the app.

In Xamarin.iOS, we can assign the `AccessibilityIdentifier` property in our apps' source code, then reference it using `x => x.Marked` in Xamarin.UITest.

## Setting the AccessibilityIdentifier, Xamarin.iOS

There are a few ways to set the `AccessibilityIdentifier` in Xamarin.iOS.

Each way accomplishes the same result. Use whichever method works best for your current code base.

For this example, I am setting the `AccessibilityIdentifier` to  `FirstAndLastNameLabel` for my UILabel.

#### 1. Storyboards, Visual Studio (Mac)

[image]

#### 2. Storyboards, Xcode

[image]

#### 3. In Code

```cs
var firstAndLastNameLabel = new UILabel
{
    AccessibilityIdentifier = "FirstAndLastNameLabel"
};
```

## Referencing Unique Identifier in Xamarin.UITest

After we've created a unique identifier for each UI control, we can then reference it in Xamarin.UITest using `x => x.Marked`;

```cs
readonly System.Func<Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery, Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery> firstAndLastNameLabelQuery = x => x.Marked("FirstAndLastNameLabel");

public string GetFirstAndLastNameLabelText()
{
    var label = app.Query(firstAndLastNameLabelQuery)?.FirstOrDefault();
    return label?.Text ?? string.Empty;
}
```

## Additional Information

#### Using `Marked` in Xamarin.UITest

https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/#using-marked-to-locate-views

#### `AccessibilityIdentifier` API

> An identifier can be used to uniquely identify an element in the scripts you write using the UI Automation interfaces

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification/1623132-accessibilityidentifier?language=objc

Comment: Hi, Brandon! Of course this is the best way. I thought there was any other way. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I have followed the pattern here but it does not seem to work. Perhaps it is an issue with the current iOS version. I added a unique AccessibilityIdentifier to a UILabel. I can see the id in the REPL tree view. When I run the query in REPL, it finds and returns the result. Yet, using the same query in UITest returns no result. Truly an enigma.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the current versions of Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.UITest. I recommend opening a new Question and posting your code so that we can take a look.

Comment: To confirm, are you saying that there's no way to select the next node/element in Xamarin.UITest? I appreciate that it's better to add unique identifiers to elements, perhaps using the AutomationId attribute, but what if an automation tester does not have access or permission to change the app's source code? Or if there's a delay to getting the developers to add the relevant IDs? Does this mean I'll either have to find some funky workaround which could take time or simply put my test on hold until the devs get round to adding the IDs?